# Set selection color and selection indicator on `LI` item using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

In http://jsfiddle.net/BZKMD/

I'm trying to set the background color to `#f5f5f5` using `li.selected` and show the green indicator bar. But i'm only able to show one of the two.

How would I show both of them?

Here is the code if you don't have access to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZKMD/):

```
<ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="selected">Home</li>
</ul>

ul.nav-items {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    display: table;
}
ul.nav-items li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px green dotted;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul.nav-items li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
ul li.selected {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
ul li.selected {
    position: relative;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #88991A;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `background-color` by using another selector, you should use `border-top` instead of background` for indicating active tab

```
ul li.selected {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 6px solid #88991a;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BZKMD/1/)

---

When you don't need `border` for inactive tabs, than too use `border` but with transparent `color` to balance the offset like `border-top: 6px solid transparent; /* For inactive tabs */`

---

**How would I've achieved this?**

I would've used `:before` pseudo with `content` set `position: absolute;` in a `relative` positioned `li`

```
ul li.selected:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 6px solid #88991a;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/BZKMD/7/)

---

> Note: You are using some redundant properties like `display:
>   table-cell;` with `float: left;` where only either one is required, than `vertical-align: middle;` and `line-height: 50px;`

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/BZKMD/10/) *(Removed redundant useless properties)*

Comment: this will lower the text 6px in comparison with the other items that are next to it. Any idea how to prevent that? make it relative ?

Comment: @invalidusername I have provided a solution for that

Comment: I don't quite like that solution, as it will no longer center my text in the div. I would rather draw the box on top of the li or something like that? what would you think would be a good approach?